# Error: unexpected 'endif'

Tags: php

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['flash'])): ?>
    <?php foreach ($_SESSION['flash'] as $type => $message): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-<?= $type; ?>">
            <?= $message; ?>
        </div>
    <?php enforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($_SESSION['flash']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Could you help me please?
It's shows me an error in my code, but its seems all it's okay.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)

Comment: This would be easier to debug if you didn't open and close PHP so much

Comment: You have missed "D"
<?php enforeach; ?> -> <?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: Your endforeach spell is wrong

Comment: thank you, I've missed 'd' in endforeach,
**solved**